# Can't load individual local with ng-src - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I ran into a problem while trying to bind a single image to a template. I've typically used repeaters when other data was present. However, here I only need to place one image and no other data. I successfully used ng-repeat in example one to call a image from online. However, a local link produces a broken image. What am I missing here?

FYI. I'm using angular seed project so the controllers are set in app.js and don't need to wrap ng-src.

**EXAMPLE 1 - Success**

```
<img ng-src="{{image}}"/>

.controller('someCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.image = 'https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3261/2801924702_ffbdeda927_d.jpg';
}])
```

**EXAMPLE 2 - Fail**

```
<img ng-src="../img/{{image}}"/>

.controller('someCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.image = 'cat.jpg';
}])
```

Comment: what does the html output (parsed) say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a syntax point of view that is correct.  I just did this in an angular project I'm working on.  Make sure the image is where it is supposed to be and that your relative path is correct.  That's about all that can be wrong here.  I don't think this is an angular issue.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Check your picture exists.

http://jsfiddle.net/s0w6eyna/

HTML

```
<img ng-src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3261/2801924702_{{image}}" />
```

JS

```
function ImageCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.image = 'ffbdeda927_d.jpg';
}
```